# php mail() returning false

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want to send the email from the server when someone submits the contact form. Here is the sample php code.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
$email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
$dept = strip_tags(trim($_POST['dept']));
$message = strip_tags(trim($_POST['message']));

if((!isset($email) || empty($email)) || (!isset($name) || empty($name)) || (!isset($dept) || empty($dept)) || (!isset($message) || empty($message))){
    echo -1;
    return;
}
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===false){
    echo -2;
    return;
}

$to = 'farooqahmadkhan003@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Splendenti Eye Wear | Contact Us";
$email_body = "Contacted by\nName: $name\nEmail: $email\nDepartment: $dept\nMessage: $message";
$headers = "noreply@farooq.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST['email'];
if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){
    echo 1; // email sent
}
else{
    echo "failed to send email";
}
}else{
echo "Invalid Request";
}
?>
```

but the mail function is returning false. Can anybody guide??

Comment: is your server configure for emails (sendmail/smtp)

Comment: How can I check that @SureshKamrushi?

Comment: [Read the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and the user comments.

Comment: @Synchro I've gone through the mail docs but found nothing wrong in the code. May be I need to configure the server for sending email.

Comment: Yes, you need to do exactly that, which is covered very well in the doc I pointed you at.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use PHPMailer to send emails from your PHP files.
Check this [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and download it. There are many documentations about PHPMailer online. You can control all the details about your mail with PHPMailer.

Answer (score -3):

try to use @ to suppress warnings:

```
if(@mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)){
    echo 1; // email sent
}
```

If this doesn't help you have a configuration issue.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem, it just suppresses the error message. `mail()` doesn't throw exceptions, so using try/catch will do nothing.

Comment: @Synchro.. you are right. deleted my last edit. Anyway: I think onyl warnings are suppressedand not all errors. Maybe you should try to post an answer.

Comment: @Farooq Khan Did my answer help you or should it be deleted?

Comment: @Wolfgang Code was correct. There was restriction form the server.